# Java Long.parseLong does not give correct value in terms of 2's complement

Tags: java, data-conversion, twos-complement

I have the following codes where I am doing conversion from hex to decimal.
`Long.parseLong("FF44C5EC",16)`. 
The output I get is this `4282697196`
But by right it should be a negative number. What else should I do to get the correct conversion with 2's complement ?

Comment: Why do you think it should be negative?

Comment: @Because I have tried to convert it via this website https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html

Comment: You will get decimal not 2's complement

Comment: @Eklavya how to get the 2's complement cause some of the places I saw on google it says use Long.parseLong but I have used but still giving me that big integer number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-) returns a signed `long`, but by "signed" it means that it can handle negative numbers if you pass a string starting with `-`, not that it knows the 2's complement.

> Parses the string argument as a signed long in the radix specified by
>   the second argument. The characters in the string must all be digits
>   of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char,
>   int) returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may
>   be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or
>   an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The
>   resulting long value is returned.

A solution could be:

```
Long.valueOf("FF44C5EC",16).intValue()
```

That prints `-12270100` as you expect.

Comment: I dont get you isnt that I am using parseLong ready ?

Comment: so should I use .intValue() will that cover all the big number and do it correctly ?

Comment: just wondering you wrote this "parseLong returns a signed long, but by "signed" it means that it can handle negative numbers if you pass a string starting with -, not that it knows the 2's complement." so it must pass the "-" manually is it ?

Comment: If you pass `-F` returns `-15`, if you pass `F` it's `16`. You can try it as well on your machine :)

Comment: yes I tried it works like you said. So I guess I will accept your answer Long.valueOf("FF44C5EC",16).intValue(). Will  be able to cover big number ?